# Facebook API | How to open invitable_friends permission dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

While installing an app, user have the option to revoke invitable_friends permission. In that case I would like to ask for invitable_friends permission once again. I've noticed apps opening invitable_friends permission request dialog, and I'm wondering how. Please have a look at the attached screenshot.

[image]

I could not find any information about this dialog anywhere.

Comment: That is just the normal login dialog, nothing special about it. If you want to re-ask for a permission that the user has declined already, you need to add an additional parameter to the login dialog call, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#handling

Comment: Thanks. Your comment actually solved my problem. If you like, post it as an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just the normal login dialog, nothing special about it.

If you want to re-ask for a permission that the user has declined already, you need to add an additional parameter to the login dialog call, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#handling